# How can I define a file naming convention of incoming files in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, naming, convention

I receive files in real-time in hdfs and they have the same naming convention.

id_name_..._timestamp

Can I somehow define this naming convention on spark (scala), so I can compare these later with the ID for example?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you use something like this :

## register udf

```
spark.udf()
  .register("get_only_file_name", (String fullPath) -> {
     int lastIndex = fullPath.lastIndexOf("/");
     return fullPath.substring(lastIndex, fullPath.length - 1);
    }, DataTypes.StringType);
```

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.input_file_name

```
#use the udf to get last token(filename) in full path
Dataset<Row> initialDs = spark.read()
  .option("dateFormat", conf.dateFormat)
  .schema(conf.schema)
  .csv(conf.path)
  .withColumn("input_file_name", get_only_file_name(input_file_name()));
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you!

But I become the content and the "input_file_name" in a DF and I need actually just to define the naming convention so that spark can automatically recognize where is the ID, where is the timestamp, etc. (perhaps in DF) when the files come.
the naming convention looks like: 
id_name_..._timestamp

Comment: I become the filenames as follows:


def getFilenames(fullpath: String) = {
      val dir = new File(fullpath)
      dir.listFiles.map(_.getName)
      }